# With Gosu 0.9-14, do I need to download it, or will my IntelliJ plugin automatically pull the update?

Tags: intellij-idea, gosu

If I recall correctly, the IJ plugin uses Maven to figure things out about Gosu.  Do I need to do anything manually, or will the IJ plugin just automagically update the Maven dependencies and get the latest version of Gosu for me?

If so, is there an easy way to verify that I've got the updated version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The IJ plugin doesn't use Maven.  If we ever make a new release of Gosu that the IJ plugin needs to incorporate, we will post a new version of the plugin on the JetBrains plugin repository.

For Gosu's 0.9-14 release, there have been no changes to the language so we aren't updating the plugin.